# AWS S3 console: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, console

I've made an account at aws, created a bucket and upload some files. I've set the bucket as an static web page and i can access to the files using the url, but now, when i get into the AWS console and into the S3 service i can't see my bucket, all I see is a message saying "An unexpected error occurred".

Any suggestions? I've got no bills pendings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd try a forced browser refresh, or log out, clear browser cache, and log in.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i'd try it and no way. I finally could make it works in an incognito browser!

Comment: Perhaps a problem with a browser plug-in.

Comment: I had to disable my CORS plugin

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had the same problem, but after deactivating CORS plugin (on Chrome) it started to work again.

Comment: That was the fix.

Comment: Also had to restart chrome.

Comment: In my case it was the JSONView extension (Chrome)

Comment: Are you referring to this extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?

Answer (score 6):

I confirm that disabling the uBlock Origin plugin on Chrome fixes this issue. It also fixes other status issues such as the word 'error' under the 'access' column on the AWS S3 console page. Simply disable the plugin, refresh the page, and all is back to normal with the correct display status.

[With uBlock Origin activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fiWM.png)

[After disabling uBlock Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgVIZ.png)

I have not tested this on Firefox, Opera or Safari.

Comment: It was uBlock Origin for me as well (Firefox).

Comment: yep there was COP plugin in chrome

Answer (score 3):

Yes it works if you diasble the cors origin plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had configured my browser to only accept SSL connections which use strong cipher suites. Amazon, for some reason, only supports one cipher suite which SSL Labs doesn't label as WEAK: `0xc02f`. If you enable that cipher suite and disable CORS-related browser extensions it should work.

[image]