# AWS Sync S3 Bucket error on Server-side encryption setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two s3 bucket: S3 (A) on my AWS Account(A) and S3(B) on my AWS Account(B). I was able to successfully export/copy my S3(A) to S3(B).

But when I checked the objects on the S3(B), it has error on the "Server-side encryption settings"

[image]

But on my S3(A) there is no server encryption .

[image]

I just run the command on my aws cli like this

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a  s3://bucket-b
```

Comment: Maybe its only a console glitch. Can you check with aws cli?

Comment: @Marcin I also tried to copy the files using aws console. I was successfully copy the files to s3(B) but when i check the server configuration. It was the same on the image above.

Comment: Is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807242/aws-s3-console-an-unexpected-error-occurred) of use?